# How to solve producer/consumer race condition with BlockingCollection<>

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I am implementing a logger which writes records to the database. In order to prevent the database writes from blocking the code which is calling the logger, I've moved the DB access to a separate thread, implemented using a producer/consumer model based on `BlockingCollection<string>`.

Here's the simplified implementation:

```
abstract class DbLogger : TraceListener
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _buffer;
    private readonly Task _writerTask;

    DbLogger() 
    {
        this._buffer = new BlockingCollection<string>(new ConcurrentQueue<string>(), 1000);
        this._writerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.ProcessBuffer, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    // Enqueue the msg.
    public void LogMessage(string msg) { this._buffer.Add(msg); }

    private void ProcessBuffer()
    {
        foreach (string msg in this._buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            this.WriteToDb(msg);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void WriteToDb(string msg);

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) 
    { 
        if (disposing) 
        {
            // Signal to the blocking collection that the enumerator is done.
            this._buffer.CompleteAdding();

            // Wait for any in-progress writes to finish.
            this._writerTask.Wait(timeout);

            this._buffer.Dispose(); 
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing); 
    }
}
```

Now, when my application shuts down, I need to make sure that the buffer is flushed before the database connection goes down. Otherwise, `WriteToDb` will throw an exception.

So, here's my naive Flush implementation:

```
public void Flush()
{
    // Sleep until the buffer is empty.
    while(this._buffer.Count > 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

The problem with this implementation is the following sequence of events:

1. There is one entry in the buffer.
2. In the logging thread, `MoveNext()` is called on the enumerator, so we're now in the body of `ProcessBuffer`'s `foreach` loop.
3. `Flush()` is called by the main thread. It sees that the collection is empty, so returns immediately.
4. The main thread closes the DB connection.
5. Back in the logging thread, the body of the `foreach` loop starts executing. `WriteToDb` is called, and fails because the DB connection has been closed.

So, my next try was adding some flags, like so:

```
private volatile bool _isWritingBuffer = false;
private void ProcessBuffer()
{
    foreach (string msg in this._buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        lock (something) this._isWritingBuffer = true;
        this.WriteToDb(msg);
        lock (something) this._isWritingBuffer = false;
    }
}

public void Flush()
{
    // Sleep until the buffer is empty.
    bool isWritingBuffer;
    lock(something) isWritingBuffer = this._isWritingBuffer;
    while(this._buffer.Count > 0 || isWritingBuffer)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

However, there's still a race condition, since the entire `Flush()` method could execute after the collection is empty but before `_isWritingBuffer` gets set to `true`.

How can I fix my `Flush` implementation to avoid this race condition?

**Note:** For various reasons, I must write the logger from scratch, so please don't answer with a suggestion that I use some existing logging framework.

Comment: why not just do lock (this) this._isWritingBuffer = true; and lock (this) this._isWritingBuffer = false; outside the foreach loop?  thus you assume you are writing until you know the collection is empty?

Comment: @tolanj: that would not work, since the enumerator is blocking. So if there's nothing in the collection, it just sits there (until `CompleteAdding()` is called. If I move the locks outside the foreach loop, `Flush` would never return until the logger was disposed.

Comment: I don't follow all your code but why are you making it so hard?  The documentation has some simple examples.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First **never ever lock on a public object**, especially `this`.

Moreover **never ever use bare booleans for synchronization**: see my blog if you want to have a glimpse in what can go wrong: **[Synchronization, memory visibility and leaky abstractions](http://pragmateek.com/synchronization-memory-visibility-and-leaky-abstractions/)** :)

Concerning the issue itself I must be missing something but why do you need such a `Flush` method?

Indeed when you're done with your logging you will dispose of the logger by calling its `Dispose` method from the main thread.

And you have implemented it in such a way that it will wait for the "write to DB" task.

If I'm wrong and you really need to synchronize with another primitive then you should use an event:

In the `DbLogger`:

```
public ManualResetEvent finalizing { get; set; }

public void Flush()
{
    finalizing.WaitOne();
}
```

And somewhere, e.g. in `ProcessBuffer` you notify when you're done with writing to DB:

```
finalizing.Set();
```

Comment: I think you're right - I may not need a flush method after all. I just need to make sure that the logger is disposed before the DB connection goes away (currently, the order of those two operations is arbitrary).

Comment: And as for your first two comments, I've corrected them (they were only incorrect in the primitive sample which I posted here)